# Re-train model with new classes

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

I have built an image classifier with 2 classes, say 'A' and 'B'. I have also saved this model, using model.save().

Now, after a certain time, the requirement arose to add one more class 'C'. Is it possible to load_model() and then add only one class to the previously saved model so that we have the final model with 3 classes ('A','B' and 'C'), without having to retrain the whole model, for classes 'A and 'B' again?

Can anyone help?

I have tried this:

I used vgg16 as a base model and pop out its last layer, freeze weights and added one dense layer (DL2), trained it for predicting 2 classes.

Then I added one more dense layer on top of DL2 say DL3, freeze weights and train with class C only but now its always predicting class C.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should check this tutorial:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining.

In short:
You can not take trained model, and add new classes.
You should make some additional 'finetuning', may be not retrain the model from scratch, but at least to train classifier (and some additional layers).

Comment: the link is broken

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply change the number of output classes in the last layer and freeze weights for the remaining layer. Retrain the weights for only the last layer.

Comment: Thanks Suji, I tried this but no luck. I used vgg16 as a base model and pop out its last layer, freeze weights and added one dense layer (DL2), trained it and predicting 2 classes. Then I added one more dense layer on top of DL2, freeze weights and train with class C only but now its always predicting class C.

Comment: In this case, we are supposed to train with all the three classes Dilip. Because the newly added dense layer is trained only to predict class C. I mean its weight is tuned so as to predict only Class C. I hope training this network with all three class data would do the trick. and retraining with all the class data would not take much time because it is just the last layer that is getting trained.

Comment: I took an example of 3 classes but in my case right now there 100 classes but it can increase to 500 in next 3 months then to ~1000 in next 6 months. Then it would be difficult to train from scratch every time. How google update their models, I'm sure they must not be doing from scratch everytime :D

Answer (score 0):

Just use a transfer learning, and create a new model.

```
model = VGG16(weights='imagenet',
                  include_top=False,
                  input_shape=(150, 150, 3))

model.pop()

base_model_layers = model.output
pred = Dense(11, activation='softmax')(base_model_layers)
model = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=pred)

# Freeze the first layers, before train it
for layer in model.layers[:-2]:
    layer.trainable = False
```