# How do i retrain the model without losing the earlier model data with new set of data

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, face-recognition

for my current requirement, I'm having a dataset of 10k+ faces from 100 different people from which I have trained a model for recognizing the face(s). The model was trained by getting the 128 vectors from the facenet_keras.h5 model and feeding those vector value to the Dense layer for classifying the faces.
But the issue I'm facing currently is

1. if want to train one person face, I have to retrain the whole model once again.

How should I get on with this challenge? I have read about a concept called transfer learning but I have no clues about how to implement it. Please give your suggestion on this issue. What can be the possible solutions to it?

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do? Retrain the original network for your specific 100 people or add a new person to the database after training?

Answer (score 1):

With transfer learning you would copy an existing pre-trained model and use it for a different, but similar, dataset from the original one. In your case this would be what you need to do if you want to train the model to recognize your specific 100 people.

If you already did this and you want to add another person to the database without having to retrain the complete model, then I would freeze all layers (set `layer.trainable = False` for all layers) except for the final fully-connected layer (or the final few layers). Then I would replace the last layer (which had 100 nodes) to a layer with 101 nodes. You could even copy the weights to the first 100 nodes and maybe freeze those too (I'm not sure if this is possible in Keras). In this case you would re-use all the trained convolutional layers etc. and teach the model to recognise this new face.

Comment: Hey @wohe1, I'm not getting how to add the new person with the label, Cause I'm using tf.keras.utils.to_categorical for one-hot encoding and it start from 0 Index, How can i append new label to the last, please help me out with this.

Comment: Currently you have a  N×100 array, you can create a new array of size N×101 filled with zeros and copy the values of the first array to the last. Then add the new entries for the new faces

Comment: So, let me give you a brief description of what I am looking into, so I'm having set 10k faces from different 100 people. The thing what I did was first getting 128d  vector values from every face present in my dataset,

Comment: Sencondly after getting those vector I have trained it using dense layers, So before training I had split the data into two (by using to_categorical for one-hot encoding ) test and train. i'm having a dataset containing the folder name 0-100, so the time when I split the data(y_data array which is the label and size of it is (10000,1)). So, if I want to retrain the model by adding a new person with the label and here again I need to split the data into two, train and test, So over here the index starts from zero it override the model data.

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is, first of all: what do you mean by 128d vector values?

Comment: so, I'm using a pre-trained model called Facenet Keras in order to e extract high-quality features from the face and predict a 128 element vector representation these features and later feeding those vector value to the dense layer for classification.

Comment: In that case just freeze all the layers up until the 128 vector and only train the weights of the last layer(s) that you addes

Comment: Yes, I have freeze all the layers until 128 vector, but the problem I'm facing currently is I'm not able to predict the previously trained face(s), I think the previous data has been lost.

Comment: So if i get it right, you only want to train on the new faces?

Comment: Yes, but I also want to retain the previously trained face data.

Comment: In that case I would create a new top layer with 101 nodes instead of 100 and copy the weights leading to the first 100 nodes from the old to the new layer. I think this might work if you can then freeze the weights leading to the first 100 nodes but not the weights to the last (new) node. I don't think this is possible out of the box with keras so you might need to create a custom layer...

Comment: I have tried this but no luck, Currently the problem I'm Facing is similar to below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50366160/re-train-model-with-new-classes?rq=1

Comment: Then I think your best option is to use the complete dataset again but only train the weights of the last layer. Think of it like this: the other nodes also need to know which faces are not the right ones so their weights need to be updated with the new faces as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your training results by saving your weights with:

```
model.save_weights('my_model_weights.h5')
```

And load them again later to resume your training after you added a new image to the dataset with:

```
model.load_weights('my_model_weights.h5')
```